# MongoDB _rand() generating same random number every time

Tags: mongodb

I've tried doing Math.random(), __rand(), but still all records in the output get the same value, is there workaround for this?

```
   db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      {
          $group:{ 
              _id: '$orderNumber',
              data: {
                $push: '$orderNumber' 
              }
          }
     },
    {
        $addFields: {
           random: _rand()
        }
    },
   {$out: 'delete'}
  ]
)
```

Output example

```
{
  _id:"MK5K44FJ5N"
  pivotData: {
    random: 0.34
  }
},
{
  _id:"HKSH755K"
  pivotData: {
    random: 0.34
  }
}
```

As you can see, same random value, hundreds of it. The purpose of these random number is so I can later index that field and distribute the processing of such documents.

Example: I have to do some Java processing of the documents later, so I plan to add that random number, and index by it, then distribute the processing of the documents across multiple threads where each thread queries for a range of such random number, since the random number is just between 1 and 100, 10 threads can each get it's own 10 number range with a few million docs each.

Comment: Are you trying to assign a random number for each `orderNumber`?

Comment: Could you please explain what is it you are looking for? Generate random numbers, okay. What is the input collection and how are you planning to use the random number with the documents? Your post is not clear.

Comment: Joe's answer is good regarding just assigning a random num it's just impossible because _rand() is on the client. However I just found that the document already has a field with 4 random digits at the end, I'll just use those digits. I'll put more details on the question about how I'm planning to use the random numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `_rand()` only exists on the client side, not the server.  This means that it is evaluated and substituted into the pipeline array prior to send the query to the server, so the pipeline that is actually sent and run looks like:

```
   db.iReconTxCollection.aggregate(
   [
      {
          $group:{ 
              _id: '$orderNumber',
              data: {
                $push: '$orderNumber' 
              }
          }
     },
    {
        $addFields: {
           random: 0.34
        }
    },
   {$out: 'delete'}
  ]
)
```

I don't know of a way to accomplish this other than generating the random numbers in the client and submitting a separate update for each document.

**Edit**

Thought of a generator that is deterministic:

```
{$addFields: {
    randomish:{
        $reduce:{
            input:{
               $regexFindAll:{
                      input:{$toString:"$_id"},
                      regex:"."
            }},
            initialValue:1,
            in:{
               $mod:[
                  {$multiply:[
                      {$indexOfBytes:["0123456789abcdef","$$this.match"]},
                      "$$value"
                  ]},
                  101
               ]
            }
         }
    }
}}
```

Comment: I can not find a way either, however, all I want is a number between 1 and 100, trying to see if some $mod operation can suffice but can not find a good way either, since I would need a differentiator for the mod on each record

Comment: If they don't have to be actually random, you could use $group to push them all into an array then $unwind the array with the index, and use $addFields and $mod the index for each document.

Comment: The do not all fit into a single grouped document if that's what you meant

Comment: They don't have to, the aggregation pipeline lets you work with oversize documents as long as they are below 16MB when you return them.  Just need to temporarily group them into an array, then unwind them back out to assign each one a unique index, then you can use mod to limit that number to the 1-100 range.

Comment: wouldn't unwind and that extra grouping be slow for a few millions?. Also tried using {$mod:[{$miliseconds: new Date()},100)} and got same value for 12K records. if operation took longer than 1milisecond it should have set different values right?

Comment: Nope, `new Date()` is also executed on the client side before sending the query.

Comment: If you are using default ObjectId for _id, that is a unique per document value that can be coerced into the range 1-101. (since 100 is not prime, that mod method tends to land on 100 and stick there if we mod by 100)

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer is correct, below what I ended up doing since our shard key has 4 random digits appended to it and I just need random numbers between 1 and 100. It would be nice to have a server side _rand() function though

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      {
          $group:{ 
              _id: '$orderNumber',
              data: {
                $push: '$orderNumber' 
              },
             randomKey:{$first:{ '$add':[{'$mod':['$shardKey',100]},1]}} 
          }
     },
   {$out: 'delete'}
  ]
)
```